# Yii2 | GridView table, communication between models does not work

Tags: php, yii2

The connection between the modules does not work, and because of this, the data in the table is not displayed. I can not understand why

Code in the controller

```
  public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new SuggestedNewsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->getAllNews(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel
        ]);
    }
```

code in suggestedNewsSearch.php

```
class SuggestedNewsSearch extends SuggestedNews
{

    public function getAllNews($params)
    {
        $query = $this::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if ($this->validate() AND !($this->load($params))) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('title'))) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'title', $this->getAttribute('title')]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('category'))) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'category', $this->getAttribute('category')]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('status'))) {
            switch (mb_strtolower($this->getAttribute('status'))) {
                case $this::APPROVED:
                    $status = $this::ACTIVE_STATUS;
                    break;
                case $this::NOT_APPROVED:
                    $status = $this::DEACTIVATED_STATUS;
                    break;
            }
            $query->andFilterWhere(['=', 'status', $status]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

code on SuggestedNews.php

```
class SuggestedNews extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    CONST ACTIVE_NEWS = 1;
    CONST ACTIVE_STATUS = 1;
    CONST DEACTIVATED_STATUS = 0;
    CONST APPROVED  = 'одобренно';
    CONST NOT_APPROVED = 'не одобренно';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'suggested_news';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['news'], 'string'],
            [['category', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['date'], 'safe'],
            [['title', 'news_source'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['category'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Category::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['category' => 'id']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'title' => 'Title',
            'news' => 'News',
            'category' => 'Category',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'news_source' => 'News Source',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
    }

    public function deleteNewsById($id)
    {
        $customer = $this::findOne($id);
        if ($customer->delete()) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public function getNewsByIdWithCategory($id){
        return $this::find()->where(['id' => $id])->with('category')->one();
    }
}
```

code on Category.php

```
class Category extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    CONST STATUS_CATEGORY_OFF = 0;
    CONST STATUS_CATEGORY_ON = 1;
    CONST NEW_CATEGORY_INTEGER = 01;
    CONST NEW_CATEGORY_NAME = 'New Category';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'category';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'status_category'], 'required'],
            [['status_category'], 'integer'],
            [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'status_category' => 'Status Category',
        ];
    }
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSuggestedNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SuggestedNews::className(), ['category' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getAllCategories(){
        return $this::find()->where(['status_category' => $this::STATUS_CATEGORY_ON])->all();
    }
}
```

my index.php file(view)

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'title',
            'filter' => true,
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'category.Category',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Category',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'filter' => true,
            'value' => function($model) {
                if($model->status == 1){
                    return $model::APPROVED;
                }else{
                    return $model::NOT_APPROVED;
                }
            }
        ],
        'date',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

and on result i have this:[result table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSERV.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJUsj.png)

[table category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rsKS.png)

[table suggested_news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnyN0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You field name and relation are the same, so You have to change Category relation name like this:

```
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory1()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
    }
//Gridview
//...
[
    'attribute' => 'category',
    'label' => 'Category',
    'value' => function($model){
         return $model->category1->name;
    }  
],
//...
//or
//...
[
    'attribute' => 'category1.name',
    'format' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Category',
],
```

Hope it will helps.